# Javascript regular expression match anything but

Tags: javascript, regex, match, string-matching

I want a regular expression that matches anything but '{{' or '{:'

test cases:

```
var t1= abcd;
var t2= abcd{{;
var t3= abcd{:efg;
```

I want them to have the output when using t.match(REGEX):

```
//"abcd".match(REGEX) -->      ["abcd"];
//"abcd{{.match(REGEX)"-->     ["abcd","{{"]
//"abcd{:efg".match(REGEX)-->  ["abcd","{:"]
```

I've tried :

```
///^[\s\S]+[^{{|{:]/           //the the match returns null
///^[\s\S]*?(?={{|{:)/         //but for t1-->matches null
///^[\s\S]+[^{{|{:]+[\s\S]*/   //but for t3--> returns abcd{{efg
```

but they always return:

```
//"abcd".match(REGEX) --> null
```

Is there a way for it to return ["abcd"] for even if there is no "{{" or "{:" character?

Comment: I don't understand the requirements or the test cases, what is it you want returned?

Comment: @minseong for example when I do t1.match(/reg1/); --> returns ["abcd"]... also when t2.match(/reg1/);-->returns ["abcd", "{{"]... also when t3.match(/reg1/)-->returns["abcd","{{"];... So far, my expression work with t2 and t3, it returns what I want. but it always return null for case t1. I tried many regex but somehow it never works for t1, I was wondering if it was even possible

Comment: Please edit the question rather than providing further information in comments. Isn't `/[\s\S]/` the same as `/./`?

Comment: @RobG but i don't think /./ recognizes the newline character

Comment: Under what logic would `"abcd{{efg".match(REGEX)-->  ["abcd","ff"]`? Where do the two `f` characters come from?

Comment: @torazaburo: I beleive, it's a typo, he meant ["abcd","{{"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^((?:[^{\n])+)({{|{:)*
```

where
((?:[^{\n])+) - first group before new line or { ,
         ({{|{:)* - optional {{ or {: group.

See https://regex101.com/r/3UOewQ/4 that I used to verify, that it works

Answer (score 0):

([^{]*)(({{)|({))*

Then you can use \1 \2 . . \n to reference the group of characters or the {{

If you need to add quotes to the beginning use: 
("[^{]*") for the first group